# Awk last octet of a filed and second field both

Tags: awk

Good morning.
I'm looking to take a hosts file and get the last octet of the IP from $1 and then print the hostname next. 
For example:

```
Input:
xxx.xxx.xxx.210         zone123 #Comment 
Output
210         zone123
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you tried to do it on your own? Or are you just looking for a solution? Read this about SO questions  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic next time.

Answer (score 1):

For a hosts file like one that I could grab, this worked:

```
awk '/^[^#]/{split($1, arr, "." ); print arr[4], $2 }' hosts
```

This will parse the file by spaces first, ignore comment lines, then print the 4th element of the first field, and the 2nd element designated by spaces.

Comment: That works to get the last octet and then the rest of the file. I only need the last octet and the 2nd field. I should have asked the question better. xxx.xxx.xxx.210 zone123 #comment in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -F "[. \t]*" '/^[0-9]+./ {print $4,$5}
```

```
echo "192.168.32.210         zone123 #Comment " | awk -F "[. \t]*" '/^[0-9]+./ {print $4,$5}'
210 zone123
```

It search for all lines starting with a number and then `.`
If found, divide line into parts and print field `$4` and `$5`